# Set Duration Units to hours in VBA when generating a new MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

The default Duration Unit for MS Project is Days, but most of our Projects require the duration units to be displayed in hours.
I use VBA to generate new Projects; does anyone know how to set MS Project Duration Units to hours in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project) object has a property called [DefaultDurationUnits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.defaultdurationunits); set it to pjHour.

For example:

```
ActiveProject.DefaultDurationUnits = pjHour
```